# Question about the Merge layout.xml - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, local.xml, best-practice

> **Question**: If a layout handle exists in the "`base/default`" package, your custom design package, and the custom package's
>   "`local.xml`", wich handles can be merged ?

1) All of the handles can be merged.

2) Only the handles in "`base/default`" can be merged.

3) Only the handles in your design package can be merged.

4) Only the handles in "`local.xml`" can be merged.

5) Only the handles in "`base/default`" and "`local.xml`" can be merged.

6) Only the handles in your design package and "`local.xml`" can be merged.

Comment: Is this a multiple choice question from the certification? What kind of answer do you expect for it?

Comment: Yes, I was not able to answer this question and I was not sure about my answer, but may I say the answer is `1)`

Comment: Without checking code i'd choose 6)

Comment: it's indeed the 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **4 days** that nobody was able to answer this question, so I did my research and I confirm that it is indeed the answer **"1)"**

> `1) All of the handles can be merged.`

**Explication:**

How the Magento layout merge works ?

**1.** When loading a theme, Magento reads the configuration of all the available modules, and checks which layout files should be loaded.

**2.** For each file, Magento tries to load it from your theme.
    If it exists in your theme, it loads it and goes directly to step 4.

**3.** If the file doesn't exist in your theme, it tries to load it from the `base/default` theme.

**4.** Magento parses the XML files and merges them into one.

**5.** Magento looks for a `local.xml` file in your theme, and appends whatever is there, to the previously merged layout handles.

*Hoping that everyone knows now.*